# Why my usage of `ThisBuild` is not working?

Tags: plugins, sbt, settings

I wrote a simple SBT plugin, which defined a `helloMessage`, and the default value is `None`:

```
lazy val helloMessage = settingKey[Option[String]]("the message for hello")

override def projectSettings = Seq(
  helloMessage in ThisBuild := None,
  hello := println("Hello from my plugin: " + helloMessage.value)
)
```

Then in a testing project, I added this plugin, and defined in `build.sbt`:

```
helloMessage in ThisBuild := Some("hello from this build")

lazy val root = project in file(".")

lazy val core = project in file("core")
```

You may notice I used `ThisBuild` for `helloMessage`.

But the problem is, when I run `./sbt helloMessage` in the testing project, it just outputs a `None`! Not the message `Some("hello from this build")` I defined!

But if I delete the two lines:

```
lazy val root = project in file(".")

lazy val core = project in file("core")
```

or just the `core` line, it will output the expected message `Some("hello from this build")`.

Where is wrong? If I have to keep the multi projects, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Start by using `buildSettings` for `in ThisBuild` settings, as suggested [in the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html#projectSettings+and+buildSettings).

Comment: Thanks, I just define `helloMessage := None` in `buildSettings`, it's OK now. But soon I found it can use the settings like `name.value` or `target.value`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, change:

```
helloMessage in ThisBuild := None
```

to

```
helloMessage in Global := None
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the initialization order. In your build.sbt file the line `helloMessage in ThisBuild := Some("hello from this build")` will be executed first. This will set the `helloMessage` setting in the global (build) scope.

Now, when any of your projects gets initialized it will run the new setting `helloMessage in ThisBuild := None`. This will overwrite the helloMessage setting in the global scope to be `None`.

One way to go around this is to remove the `ThisBuild` from inside your project settings. That is, you keep the `ThisBuild` scope in your main build.sbt file but keep local scope (`helloMessage := None`) inside the project settings in your plugin definition.